# Kinect - how to compute the acceleration of hand joints over 1 sec

Tags: c#, iphone, accelerometer, kinect, acceleration

I have an application which uses the Microsoft Kinect camera device.

At each point I can obtain the position of my hand in the 3 Dimensional space ( X - Y - Z ) and I want to compute acceleration of my hand over each second on each axis.

Basically, I have the coordinates of a start point and also for after a second from that start point, and I want to compute the acceleration of my hand between those 2 points.

`StartPoint - (x1, y1, z1)`

`EndPoint after 1 sec from StartPoint ( 30 frames ) - (x2, y2, z2)`

`Acceleration between StartPoint and EndPoint = ?`

Also I can obtain all the other coordinates of my hand over time, but I want to compute the acceleration in the period of time between start point and end point.

Could you please explain or show me how?

Comment: This isn't a Kinect question. This is a basic math/physics question. The answer is you cannot given your information. Acceleration (a) is the change in velocity (v) over time (a = dv/dt), so you need two velocity measurements, so a=(v1-v0)/(t1-t0). You don't have two velocity measurements, you have two position measurements, meaning you can calculate the velocity, v = dp/dt = (p1-p0)/(t1-t0).

Comment: That's why I mentioned that I have a kinect. With the kinect I can get the position of my joints at each second. Moreover, it computes the position of your joint at each frame, given the fact that 1 second has 30 frames. So I have a lot of position, not only those 2. I mentioned those 2 because I want to compute the acceleration between them.

Comment: I see your post on the physics SX site. Please don't post duplicates.

Comment: http://www.ugrad.math.ubc.ca/coursedoc/math101/notes/applications/velocity.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distance from StartPoint to EndPoint is a vector with 3 values, and it can gives you the speed (distance unity/second)

`velocity(EndPoint.X - StartPoint.X, EndPoint.Y - StartPoint.Y, EndPoint.Z - StartPoint.Z)`

Now, if you want the acceleration, you'll have to do the same with two *velocity* values: The velocity at the startpoint, and the velocity one second later.

`acceleration(EndVelocity.X - StartVelocity.X, EndVelocity.Y - StartVelocity.Y, EndVelocity.Z - StartVelocity.Z)`

*acceleration* represents the acceleration for each axes (X, Y and Z) and is expressed in (distance unity/second²)